# Pattern matching on function application in a pattern match?

Tags: haskell

I'd like to pattern match against a value returned from function application. For instance:

If I have a [`Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html) and I'd like to alternate on a key being in that map, do I have a better option than:

```
f map k = case map !? k of
            Just _  -> foo
            Nothing -> bar
```

In this particular case I could just as easily use `member` and guard, like:

```
f map k | member k map = foo
        | otherwise    = bar
```

but would prefer to use pattern matching in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example *does* use pattern matching, but just in a `case` expression. But I think what you're looking for is the `ViewPatterns` extension, which can be useful for eliminating boilerplate (in particular in a `case` expression, where you can use both pattern matching and guards together).

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
f k ((!? k)-> Just _) = foo
f _ _ = bar
```

Notice though that you need to switch the order of the arguments in order for `k` to be in scope in the view pattern for the seconds argument.

But I don't think this is better than your first version of `f`.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, thanks! Corollary: does the usual `@` syntax work for view patterns (e.g. if I need the map reference inside the function?) `f k map@((!? k) -> Just _) = foo map` ?

Comment: Yeah I think so, but give it a try yourself